# how to use long long int and remove segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    long long int a[10^9],sum=0;
    int n,i,length;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(0<=a[i]<=10^10)
        {
        scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
        }
   }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+a[i];   
    }

    printf("%lld",sum);
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
    return 0;
}
```

i dont know the reason why i am getting the segentation fault this code runs fine for this input 1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005

Comment: `^` is the XOR operator in C, not the exponent operator.

Comment: `10 ^ 9 == 3`; `10 ^ 10 == 0`. `0<=a[i]<=10^10` is legal, but it doesn't do what you think it does. It's equivalent to `(0 <= a[i]) <= 10^10`. `(0 <= a[i])` yields either `0` or `1`; that value is then compared to `10^10`, which is `0`.

Comment: @KeithThompson `^` has lower priority than `<=`, so `<= 10^10` should be change to `<= (10^10)`.

Comment: @EricWang: Good catch! So `0<=a[i]<=10^10` is equivalent to `((0 <= a[i]) <= 10) ^ 10` (I hope I got that right this time!)

Comment: regarding this line: 'if(0<=a[i]<=10^10)'   I think this is actually trying to check if the contents of a[i] is within a certain range.   However, a[i] has not been set and 10^10  is 0, so the chances of a long long int located on the stack, being 0 are rather slim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues in your code:

- `0<=a[i]<=10^10` is not correct, should change to `0<=a[i] && a[i]<=(10^10)`
- `^` is a bitwise xor, not power,
- In your `for` loop, you always compare before read element of `a[]`, so you need to read first, then compare.
- use `unsigned long long`, don't need `int` at end.

Check this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NUM 1000000000ULL
#define MIN_NUM 0ULL

int main() {
    int n,i;
    printf("input number count: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    unsigned long long a[n],sum=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("input number[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%llu",&a[i]);
        if(a[i]<MIN_NUM || a[i]>MAX_NUM) {
            a[i] = 0;
            printf("\t(ignored, due to out of range [%llu, %llu])\n", MIN_NUM, MAX_NUM);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        sum+=a[i];
    }

    printf("\nsum: %llu\n",sum);
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
    return 0;
}
```